# what are the options to close manual the port correctly or release the port on rhel machines?

Tags: networking, redhat, port, socket, netstat

we have redhat 7.5 server

we are suspect that port 50070 not closed correctly by the service , ( we check by netstat and PID not found ) but from the log we can see that port is in use

so we try to do the following for example ,

```
ss --kill state listening src :50070
ss: unrecognized option '--kill'
Usage: ss [ OPTIONS ]
       ss [ OPTIONS ] [ FILTER ]
   -h, --help          this message
   -V, --version       output version information
   -n, --numeric       don't resolve service names
   -r, --resolve       resolve host names
   -a, --all           display all sockets
   -l, --listening     display listening sockets
   -o, --options       show timer information
   -e, --extended      show detailed socket information
   -m, --memory        show socket memory usage
   -p, --processes     show process using socket
   -i, --info          show internal TCP information
   -s, --summary       show socket usage summary
   -b, --bpf           show bpf filter socket information
   -Z, --context       display process SELinux security contexts
   -z, --contexts      display process and socket SELinux security contexts
   -N, --net           switch to the specified network namespace name

   -4, --ipv4          display only IP version 4 sockets
   -6, --ipv6          display only IP version 6 sockets
   -0, --packet        display PACKET sockets
   -t, --tcp           display only TCP sockets
   -u, --udp           display only UDP sockets
   -d, --dccp          display only DCCP sockets
   -w, --raw           display only RAW sockets
   -x, --unix          display only Unix domain sockets
   -f, --family=FAMILY display sockets of type FAMILY

   -A, --query=QUERY, --socket=QUERY
       QUERY := {all|inet|tcp|udp|raw|unix|unix_dgram|unix_stream|unix_seqpacket|packet|netlink}[,QUERY]
```

but ss not include the kill flag

what are the option to close the port correctly or release the port on rhel machines ?

the log is:

```
2020-07-18 21:26:22,753 INFO  impl.MetricsSystemImpl (MetricsSystemImpl.java:shutdown(606)) - NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2020-07-18 21:26:22,753 ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1783)) - Failed to start namenode.
java.net.BindException: Port in use: linux.gg.com:50070
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.constructBindException(HttpServer2.java:1001)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindForSinglePort(HttpServer2.java:1023)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:1080)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:937)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeHttpServer.start(NameNodeHttpServer.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:1001)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:985)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1710)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1778)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindListener(HttpServer2.java:988)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindForSinglePort(HttpServer2.java:1019)
        ... 9 more
2020-07-18 21:26:22,755 INFO  util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 1
2020-07-18 21:26:22,757 INFO  namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at 
************************************************************/
[root@linux hdfs]#
[root@linux hdfs]#
[root@linux hdfs]# netstat -tulpn | grep 50070 ( no PID number is returned )
```

Comment: Why do you believe that the port is not closed?

Comment: crossposted by the same user: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599688/what-are-the-options-to-close-manual-the-port-correctly-or-release-the-port-on-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open network socket is like a filehandle: once the program that holds the handle exits, the socket is definately closed. So I sugest the following (execute as root):

`ss -tulpn | grep ":50070"`

review the result, if any, that looks similar to this:

```
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port              
udp    UNCONN     0      0      0.0.0.0:68                 0.0.0.0:*                   users:(("dhclient",pid=1670,fd=6))
udp    UNCONN     0      0      127.0.0.1:323                0.0.0.0:*                   users:(("chronyd",pid=1540,fd=1))
udp    UNCONN     0      0         [::1]:323                [::]:*                   users:(("chronyd",pid=1540,fd=2))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128    0.0.0.0:22                 0.0.0.0:*                   users:(("sshd",pid=1583,fd=3))
```

and if you find a program holding the port open, kill it with the kill command:

`kill <pid>`

But since the program that holds the open port is a service, I really suggest you consider other ways of closing the port:

- `systemctl stop <service>` - that stops the service, and once it exits, the open port is gone as well...
- modifying the config of the service not to open the port in question
- use a firewall to deny access to this port

Comment: no PID from ss command and service is down , but from the logs its clear that port is in use . so what we can do?

Comment: Could you share the log entries that lead you to the assumption that the port is still in use? Please edit them into your question.

Comment: see please the update question

Comment: You were supposed to put that log in the question, and not inside my answer... Anyway, I accepted the edit. I would guess that the port is in use by the service itself.. Check the Hadoop config for the open port!

Comment: what you means - Check the Hadoop config for the open port!?

Comment: exactly. You prooved with netstat and ss, that the port is not held by any other service, so it must be hadoop - which has already exited, that's why you do not see the port open...

Comment: sorry - not understand  - "which has already exited"  , if Hadoop already exists then why we not get any PID from port , please , explain exactly what you mean because your answer is very  general

Comment: No, what I meant is the timeline: In the moment when you execute netstat, Hadoop already quitted because of the exception... as a result, even if hadoop had that port open, you do not see it, because hadoop is not running by the time you execute netstat!

Comment: You deserve "bonus points" for handling this one  :)